# How to insert clickable link to html tag in shiny?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have added footer in my shiny app using html tag with fluidPage():

```
tags$footer(HTML(sprintf("For further information visit www.website.com", 
                         align = "center", 
                         style = "position:absolute; width: 100%; color: white;")
```

I need help making the link clickable. Can someone help me with the correct syntax in this example?

Also, any suggestions where to learn more about HTML & CSS implementation and syntax in shiny would be very useful.

Comment: The HTML syntax to create a link is <a href = "www.website.com" target = "new">Click here for website</a>. Does that help you?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @edv on the long run you are better off using shiny's (or htmltools') `tag` function instead of raw HTML. Please see [this](https://unleash-shiny.rinterface.com/htmltools-overview.html?#alternative-way-to-write-tags).

Comment: @ismirsehregal thank you for the suggestion. Do you know exaclty why is this the case?

Comment: @edv it is outlined in the chapter I linked. You can use shiny tag-related functions (`library(htmltools)`) to customize the tag which would take more time with raw HTML (from within R).

Comment: @ismirsehregal I see, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [HTML a Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$footer(
    "For further information visit ",
    tags$a(
      "www.google.com",
      target = "_blank",
      href = "https://www.google.com/"
    ),
    style = "position: absolute; width: 100%; color: black; text-align: center;"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I tried this method, but it hightlights the whole sentence. Is there a way to specify to only highlight the website?

Comment: Sure - please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you, this solves my questions.